# Connect to a server on a private network

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I am learning how to create an ubuntu server to use to host a database and run a script as a thread to do some things for my graduation project...

I installed ubuntu server with lamp environment and managed to connect it to an ethernet local network that connects to the internet .. my design looks like this

[image]

except the router is also connected to a dsl modem and to the internet...

I can easily connect to the server from the local network but how can I connect to it from outside this private network ?

I know the router public ip address and the server private ip address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `port forwarding`. mean, in your router settings you define that incoming requests to specific port/protocol will redirects to specific ip (of the ubuntu).

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding

Comment: Thank you I searched how to configure port forwarding for my router and found what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up port forwarding on the router such that the router's external port 80 is forwarded to the server's private port 80.

What router is it? Its guide should detail how to set up port forwarding